Blender Stretching Bendy Bone Rig Issues
I started using Blender a few months ago and I am experiencing some issues.
So I built a bendy rubber like rig for my Lego character using stretch to. (Displayed in B-bones, you can see it in the image below)
But after parenting the figure's legs with the bones and trying to move them, the right leg somehow moves in a funky way and doesn't really follow my rig, while the left one moves normally. Their weights are the same.
Here are a few images.

A close up shot.

A side view of the rig.

Their weights are absolutely the same.


What should I do next or check to fix it? Please, can anybody who knows Blender help me? I have so many questions. :(

hello please share your file

This looks like your mesh is assigned to other bones than the ones you expect. Does this answer your question? Parenting Mesh to Bones Issue (see the weight paint section at the end of my answer).
